# PayPal DoDirectPayment - what's going on?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I created the sandbox account, made it to a business pro.

Set the credentials in API and it worked.

Used the card number from buyer account and it worker.

It worked couple of times in row and now it's not working.
It keeps saying: " This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.". I checked 100 times the credentials and it's all fine, btw it worked already. But suddenly it just stopped.

Here is the API Call from PHP script:

```
<?php

$requestParams = array(
    'METHOD' => 'DoDirectPayment',
    'USER' => $apiUsername,
    'PWD' => $apiPassword,
    'SIGNATURE' => $apiSignature,
    'VERSION' => '',
    'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
    'IPADDRESS' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    'CREDITCARDTYPE' => 'Visa',
    'ACCT' => $cardNumber,
    'EXPDATE' => $cardNumberExpDate,
    'CVV2' => '123', 
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'Testko',
    'LASTNAME' => 'Testic',
    'STREET' => 'Zmajova',
    'CITY' => 'Novi Sad',
    'STATE' => 'BG',
    'COUNTRYCODE' => 'RS',
    'ZIP' => '11000',
    'AMT' => '100.00',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
    'DESC' => 'Testing'
);
$requestParamsEncded = '';
foreach ($requestParams as $var => $val) {
    $requestParamsEncded .= '&' . $var . '=' . urlencode($val);
}
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Why and what's going on?
Is this a bug in sandbox or what?

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change the API credentials at some point to a different seller account?

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure. In "Sandbox emails and SMS notifications" list I see the list of received payments, after that it just stopped.

Comment: It's working now, did not do anything. But now I have issue with web hooks. It's not pinging my URL at all. Pretty weird. It's all in sandbox.